# How to secure service account credentials in an Android application?

Tags: android, security, google-cloud-platform, service-accounts

I have an android app which communicates with Google cloud api services like speech to text, translation, NLP etc. The application is using a service account to do this and the private key file is stored in the application itself. I understand that is a bad practice as anyone can see it using dissembler but I am not sure where else to store it for an android device.

The following post suggests to store this file on a build server:

https://brightinventions.pl/blog/securing-your-google-service-account-key-in-builds/

However, I think that it does not fix the issue as the service credential file is getting included in the publish package.

Please let me know if you can think of a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not embed service account credentials in applications. Service Account credentials have a permanent lifetime which means you will be breached. You can delete service account credentials, but then you will have to re-release your application.

You have several options:

1. Implement Google OAuth so that your users authenticate with Google Accounts. When authenticating use the correct Google OAuth Scopes to provide temporary permissions.
2. Implement temporary access tokens. Your users will connect to your website, authenticate and your code will give them a temporary access token created from service account credentials. This access token will expire. The default is 3600 seconds but you can control this.
3. You users will make all requests thru your website API's. You control authentication of the users. Your website code then makes the API requests on behalf of the users. This is not an ideal solution as all traffic goes thru your website (Compute Engine, App Engine, etc.) and you will pay for that bandwidth.

Comment: Thanks John - appreciate it!